# How can I run my test 50 times in Chrome?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Junit, Selenium and Java.

I would like to run my test like 50 times (for example) in Chrome. 
I saw so many time how to run tests in parrallele. But, if I'm not wrong it's for running my test on IE, Chrome and FF in the same time.

I'm trying to understand how I can do load test with Selenium : I would like to run my test in the same time on Chrome 50 times.

Should I use the grid?

EDIT For @JeffC : 
I thought I was clear. I read a lot of topics/ articles. I know grid are existing but this solution is too big for me because it's for run multiple times and on different browser types. I just want to run multiple times my test on browsers. 
to solve it, I tried : tests in parrallele && grid -> not working because it run the 3 browsers type (IE, Chrome and FF) not just 10 Chrome

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You didn't mention any articles you read, you didn't post any code that you have tried and what the result was. SO is about helping anyone that actually puts some effort into researching their question before posting a clear and concise question. This question is not clear and concise. You said you want to do load testing and Luiz answered correctly Selenium is not the tool for that. You asked if you should use the grid which is asking for a tool recommendation which I already commented on. If you want to run a test 50 times, slap a for loop around it and loop 50 times... what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For load testing you should use a tool built for this purpose. I recommend using Apache's JMeter. It's simple and built exactly for load testing web services such as yours.

Selenium could be used for load testing, however it is not recommended. 
https://saucelabs.com/blog/ask-a-selenium-expert-should-i-test-load-with-selenium